# iFrame doesn't work in Chrome (works fine in FF, IE and Safari)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I have an iFrame that works fine in FF, IE and Safari. In Chrome, the iFrame doesn't work. It's not even visible.

Link: http://kamersoptwitter.nl/link/Amsterdam/16985-huigenbos

The iFrame loads with a width and height of 100%, once loaded it's resized using javascript to a specific width and height (to match with the bar on top of the screen).

The code is use for the iFrame:

```
<iframe id="kamers-iframe" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" src="<?=URL?>"></iframe>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks the same in FF and Chrome for me. Chrome 15.0.874.121 m

Comment: The link looks the same in Chrome, Safari and FF on my Mac? Seems fine to me...

Comment: I get multiple errors in IE8, in chrome 18 the iframe with 'Meer weten over deze kamer' etc is visible

Comment: @AlexK. If you click on the link, do you see the website "Kamertje.nl" below the black topbar? That's the website loaded in the iFrame. If the background remains grey, the iFrame doesn't works. Apprently it does work for some versions of Chrome?! Really, really strange.

Comment: The 1st line of text I see is (Kamertje.nl, al meer dan 70.000 ....) this is version 18 (a beta)

Answer (score 1):

you may post your complete code to help you better.

I have tested your code with different url,iframe [works well](http://jsfiddle.net/r7kC5/) in Chrome ,That may be your code problem.